# ASP.NET - Return json repeats the linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use autocomplete in my mvc app. I think I was close to make this work but when I tried to return the value, it repeats the linq query and replace the result.

here's what I have..

my controller

```
public JsonResult Index(String Prefix)
{

    List<EmployeeModels> ObjList = new List<EmployeeModels>()
    {

        new EmployeeModels {EmployeeId="1",empName="Latur" },
        new EmployeeModels {EmployeeId= "2",empName="Mumbai" },
        new EmployeeModels {EmployeeId="3",empName="Pune" },
        new EmployeeModels {EmployeeId="4",empName="Delhi" },
        new EmployeeModels {EmployeeId="5",empName="Dehradun" },


    };

    var _empId = (from N in ObjList
                    where N.empName.StartsWith(Prefix)
                  select new { N.empName });

    return Json(_empId); //its correct until here but i dont know why
}
```

when the code run the return `Json(_empId)` its comeback to line "*Where N.empName...."*

SOLUTION:
Just add `ToList()` in the query like `select new {N.empName}).ToList();`
or in the `return Json (_empId.ToList());`

UPDATE:
The autocomplete work but it did not show the suggestion. when i press key down keyboard, the field change to the suggestion text. my point is the suggestion box is missing, anyone khow how to fix it?

Comment: Probably the `Index` method above uses `HttpGet`, which repeated the query when re-called by GET request. Try to limit the method scope so that it won't repeating the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made changes in your Linq query. Now you will get list of object.

```
public JsonResult Index(String Prefix)
{

List<EmployeeModels> ObjList = new List<EmployeeModels>()
{

    new EmployeeModels {EmployeeId="1",empName="Latur" },
    new EmployeeModels {EmployeeId= "2",empName="Mumbai" },
    new EmployeeModels {EmployeeId="3",empName="Pune" },
    new EmployeeModels {EmployeeId="4",empName="Delhi" },
    new EmployeeModels {EmployeeId="5",empName="Dehradun" },


};

var _empId = (from N in ObjList
                where N.empName.StartsWith(Prefix)
              select new EmployeeModels { N.empName }).ToList();

return Json(_empId); 
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks it worked to stop from repeating. but still the autocomplete is not working. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You should replace :

```
return Json(_empId);
```

With :

```
return Json(_empId.ToList());
```

Comment: I got error when i tried this. " IEnumerable<<anonymous type: string empName>>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' ..." . thanks for helphing.

Comment: But it worked if i change it to " return Json(_empId.ToList()); "

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below changes in the return statement

```
return Json(_empId);
```

to

```
return Json(_empId, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I used `microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc`  so i cant call `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`